# Getting anonymous notifications everyday two times

Tags: rooting, security

The notification title : test

Notification message : running

I would like to understand whether this notification is from the system or someone trying to hack my phone. Two weeks back I suspect some unknown app so I have deleted a app called "update service" I have attached the screenshot of the notification
[image]

[image]

Comment: What was the name of the app you removed? Do yourself a favour and run anti virus or anti malware app.

Comment: Hi. Consider [edit]ing and mentioning the device model and Android version in case the Update Service is a part of the OS.

Comment: Also posted on [Google Support - Android Help](https://support.google.com/android/thread/259577803/getting-a-notification-everyday-from-update-service). Not sure if the counter on "I have the same problem" can be trusted or not, but if it's correct, then perhaps it's a genuine but misfired push notification test.

Comment: App name was "Update service" Android Version: 13 Device : Realme